# Машинная генерация художественных узоров в векторных полях

Tags: python, массивы, машинное-обучение, numpy, matplotlib

Пытаюсь переписать данную статью: [Рисуем, программируя. Машинная генерация художественных узоров в векторных полях](https://proglib.io/p/risuem-programmiruya-mashinnaya-generaciya-hudozhestvennyh-uzorov-v-vektornyh-polyah-2020-02-06) с псевдокода на язык Python. Машинное обучение только начал изучать, отсюда и возникает следующий вопрос: Как построить сетку углов и вывести её через PyCharm?
Я нахожусь на данном этапе:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

width = 100
height = 100

left_x = int(width * -0.5)
right_x = int(width * 1.5)
top_y = int(height * -0.5)
bottom_y = int(height * 1.5)

resolution = int(width * 0.01)

num_columns = int((right_x - left_x) / resolution)
num_rows = int((bottom_y - top_y) / resolution)

grid=np.ndarray((num_columns, num_rows))
grid[:,:]=math.pi * 0.25
```

В данном коде я создаю массив grid, в котором 200 строк и 200 столбцов, в которые вносится угол 'default_angle'. Прошу подсказать, в верном ли я направлении движусь и как "отрисовать" сетку, как в прикреплённой ссылке. Предполагаю, что необходимо использовать matplotlib.

За любой конструктивный ответ буду благодарен.

Comment: Используйте matplotlib для вывода поля векторов: https://pyprog.pro/mpl/mpl_quiver.html . PyCharm к выводу никакого отношения не имеет, считайте что это просто навороченный редактор кода.

Comment: В данной вами ссылке - векторы - это стрелки. Нет ли аналога, где используется вектор в виде линии?

Comment: Для демонстрации векторного поля пойдет и со стрелками. Чтобы рисовать линии используйте `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`, например, см. примеры тут: https://jenyay.net/Matplotlib/Figures